# If $X$ has the same distribution as $-X$, then $X$ has the same distribution of $2XI_{\{|X| \leq M\}}-X$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Let $X$ be a random variable. Is the following true?

If $X$ has the same distribution as $-X$, then $X$ has the same distribution of $2XI_{\{|X| \leq M\}}-X$ where $M > 0$ is a fixed real number.

I tried to look for a suitable Borel transformation but got nothing. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your claim is true. Here comes the proof: Let the underlying sampling space be $\Omega$, with generic elements $\omega$. Fix $M>0$. Let $Y_M=X(2\mathbb{I}_{|X|\leq M}-1)$. We want to show that $\mathbb{P}(X\in A)=\mathbb{P}(Y_M\in A)$, for any $A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. Let $A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, and $M>0$, defining $S_M=\{\omega: |X(\omega)|\leq M\}$,

$$\mathbb{P}(Y_M\in A)=\mathbb{P}(\{\omega: Y_M(\omega)\in A\})=\mathbb{P}(\{\omega: Y_M(\omega)\in A\}\cap S_M)+\mathbb{P}(\{\omega: Y_M(\omega)\in A\}\cap S_M^c)$$
$$=\mathbb{P}(\{\omega: X(\omega)\in A\}\cap S_M)+\mathbb{P}(\{\omega: -X(\omega)\in A\}\cap S_M^c)=\mathbb{P}(X\in A)$$

Where the second equality follows from splitting $\{\omega:Y_M(\omega)\in A\}$ into the union of its intersection with the disjoint sets $ S_M$ and $ S_M^c$, the third one follows from $Y_M(\omega)=X(\omega)$ for $\omega\in S_M$ and $Y_M(\omega)=-X(\omega)$ for $\omega\in S_M^c$, and the fourth one from the fact that $\mathbb{P}(X\in A)=\mathbb{P}(-X\in A)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll look into it!

Comment: It is entirely correct but you have a typo in the third line. It should be $Y_M$ instead of $Y$. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I edited it. I hope it was helpful.

Comment: Very clear and helpful. Thanks again.